# My app not appear in the android market of my T-Mobile Huawei Comet phone

Tags: android, google-play

I've been working on and searching around for almost a month to find a way to solve this problem. Now I think I should ask for help from you guys.
I developed my 1st android app on Android 1.5 and published on android market. I saw my app successfully show on the website of Android market but I have no way to find it on my phone's android market. My phone is the prepaid T-mobile Huawei Comet phone which runs Android 2.2.

After a few search, I found out its possible some 1.5-based apps don't work really well on android 2.2. Fingers crossed, but I made another version of my app based on Android 2.2. After that, I tested my app thoroughly and it works completely fine on my emulator with different settings. Particularly, it works fine with the minSdk = 6, up to 8. I also tested it with different screen size and also included the settings of  `android:smallScreens = "true"` in my AndroidManifest.xml file since I learned from the internet that the Huawei phone has QVGA screen which sometimes prevents it from seeing most of apps on android market. Below is a part of my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.agitjob.ktv"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.05">
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="false"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.external_storage" />
```

I was pretty sure my app would show up on phone's android market after I updated the settings like that but STILL. My phone still can't see it on android market. I asked my friend who has a HTC Evo and he couldn't see it either. I tried to go to the android market through firefox to try install my app from there, but unfortunately, my Huawei is greyed out in the device list and the site says "This item is not compatible with your device".

I've been searching around and it seems there's no way to figure out what make the app incompatible with my phone. Is it by any chance related to the processor requirement or the size of the app? Oh, and one more thing, I purchased this Huawei comet as a prepaid phone but never activate the sim card. Is it possible the reason? But if that's the case, my friend should see the app on his phone thou.

Here's the link to my app on android market. I hope to get help/advice from all of you guys. I am totally lost now. Thank you very much.

My app: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.agitjob.ktv&feature=search_result

PS: If you have time, please check if you can see my app on your phone and test if it works fine or not. I really appreciate you all spending time reading my question.

Cheers,
Agit

UPDATE: I just tested today with HTC Glacier and it has the same problem. Any help please??

Comment: Take the uses-feature 's out and try.

Comment: @Blundell : Thanks for your quick help. I'll give it a try and get back to you shortly.
But, isn't it I need to state those 2 features to filter out devices without external storage and touch screen? Since my app needs to read/write data on sd card.

Geeez, and I'm Agit. I think stackoverflow gives me that random name ^^ I'm such a newbie here LOL

Comment: Thanks Blundell heaps. It works now =D I can see my app through android market on my phone and downloaded it flawlessly. 
The only thing is my friend which has HTC Evo running android 2.2.1 still can't see it. Any thought???

Comment: @Agit - I repaired your accounts for you...

Answer (score 0):

In the Android Market Developper Console, select your application details, and if you scroll down the options, in the Tab where you select target countries and so on, you've got an option listing all compatible devices, start there to check if yours has been filtered out and why.

check [this link](https://market.android.com/support/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=fr&answer=1286017&ctx=go)