# This app is incompatible with your device after testing on the same device?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, apportable

I have successfully converted my game that I made with SpriteBuilder to a working Android version. When I run apportable load the app loads up onto my Moto G and runs as desired. Since then I have submitted my game to the Google Play Store. However when I visit my app page on my Moto G I cannot install the app onto my phone and I am greeted with the message "This app is incompatible with your device".

This is strange as I tested the app on my Moto G and it was working as desired. Please can someone shed some light onto why this may be occurring. I have attached my AndroidManifest.XML for your reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.jgapplications.FW"
          android:sharedUserId="com.jgapplications.FW"
          android:installLocation="auto"
          android:versionCode="1394245849"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="false"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:name="com.apportable.app.VerdeApplication"
                 android:hasCode="true"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:theme="@style/FullScreenActivity"
                 android:debuggable="false"
                 android:largeHeap="false"
                 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
>        <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs" android:value="v cxx System icu CoreFoundation CommonCrypto crypto_1_01f ssl_1_01f Security SystemConfiguration CFNetwork Foundation freetype CoreGraphics BridgeKit OpenAL ffi CoreText CoreAudio AudioFile AudioUnit AudioToolbox verde" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="verde" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.app_name" android:value="Flappy Wings" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.splash_screen_type" android:value="letterbox" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.orientation" android:value="portrait" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.opengles2" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.opengles.fast_color" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.abi_list" android:value="" />
        <activity android:name="com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity"
                  android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.apportable.media.AudioManagerService" android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:theme= "@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

Comment: do you have a custom rom, dpi mod or something like that?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I am very new to this all and I don't know what either of them are so I am assuming that I don't have them?

Comment: if you dont know them, you don't use them ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. be sure that prior development builds are uninstalled
2. remember the android:required="false", if given
   eg:
   [App is incompatible with all devices after publishing to the Market but same was working when moved directly to the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007883/app-is-incompatible-with-all-devices-after-publishing-to-the-market-but-same-was?rq=1)

more:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

3. min sdk version and current android version should be compatible
4. ressources
   eg [My app does not appear in the android market of my Samsung Galaxy S phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089458/my-app-does-not-appear-in-the-android-market-of-my-samsung-galaxy-s-phone?rq=1)

i hope you could find something!

Answer (score 0):

first clear playstore data from Settings > Application Manager > All > Google Play Store > Clear data. and than check it will solve your problem